# How to update datasource in Angular Kendo UI using $resource

Tags: angularjs, resources, kendo-ui

It works when updating datasource in controller.It doesn't work when putting the datasource updating into $resource.

[code link](http://jsbin.com/IsihEZi/2/)

```
//Works
$scope.thingsOptions = {
    dataSource: {
        data: [0]
    }
};

//Doesn't work
myService2.getAllItems().then(
function (data) {
    $scope.items = data;
  $scope.thingsOptions = {
    dataSource: {
        data: [data.found]
    }
};
},
function (errorMessage) {
    $scope.error = errorMessage;
});
```

Comment: Can you provide error message or console message?